# Aggregation on the basis of an attribute of an ObjectField then sort Nested Fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Let's say I have documents like these-

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "threat": {
        "application_number": 1234,
    }
    "score_algorithms": [
        {
            "score": 21,
        },
        {
            "score": 93,
        }    
    ],
    "max_similarity": 93,
}

{
    "_id": 2,
    "threat": {
        "application_number": 1348,
    }
    "score_algorithms": [
        {
            "score": 45,
        },
        {
            "score": 67,
        }    
    ],
    "max_similarity": 67,
}

{
    "_id": 3,
    "threat": {
        "application_number": 1234,
    }
    "score_algorithms": [
        {
            "score": 98,
        },
        {
            "score": 51,
        }    
    ],
    "max_similarity": 98,
}
```

Now the agenda here is to -

- Sort these documents according to the maximum similarity attribute `max_similarity`
- Then, Aggregate the documents according to `threat.application_number`
- For example, first result to come up should have a grouping of all documents where `threat.application_number` is 1234 (which has the max value of `max_similarity`). Second entry would be a grouping of all documents where `threat.application_number` is 1348 and so on and so forth.
- All documents should internally have a sorted `score_algorithms` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For requirements 1. and 2. i.e., get the documents grouped and sorted you can use the [`order`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) parameter in the aggregation definition.

To retrieve the `score_algorithms` field in the aggregation, use a [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) sub aggregation.

You will only be able to retrieve the documents up to the `size` parameter of the `top_hits` aggregation. If you have a large number of documents for a single `application_number` it is likely to be slow.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "applications" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "threat.application_number",
                "order": [{"stats.max": "desc"}]
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "stats" : { "stats" : { "field" : "max_similarity" } },
                "applications_fields": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "max_similarity": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "_source": {
                            "includes": [ "score_algorithms", "max_similarity" ]
                        },
                        "size" : 100
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: let me just try this, will get back then. thanks :)

Comment: I have updated the query. You need to add another [stats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-stats-aggregation.html) sub aggregation for the `max_similarity` field to be able to sort on its value.

Comment: This indeed helped. But one question, I see we have set initial size=0 for only getting aggregation results. How can I get the same as a paginated result?